# Is possible to create a single file to store all Javadoc Info?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this question because I'm creating documentation with Enunciate, and by adding examples through Javadoc, the file gets too big. So I was thinking if it was possible to create a class, for example, an ENUM, with all my Javadoc's information, and in the specific method that I want to document, just call the ENUM.

Example:

```
/**
* @requestExample application/json {{ENUM.getPagesExample}}
**/
public Page getPages() 

instead of:
/**
 * @requestExample application/json {
 * "TEST1":"TEST1
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1",
 * "TEST1":"TEST1"
 * }}

**/
public Page getPages()
```

There is a way to do this?
Because I have so many @requestExample's and the class will be so big...

Appreciate all the attention!

Comment: Take a look at `@value` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#value. You may be interested in [@link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link) too.

Comment: @Yann39
You can't put a "@value" or "@link" inside "@responseExample" or it won't parse...